# Copy different ranges of a worksheet based on contents of a cell to different worksheets

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

There is a three column data in the main worksheet named 'Main Data" of my workbook named 'BOM'. In worksheet ' Main data' there is a single cell Range named 'copy_rows'  where a number is entered. On the basis of this number (Suppose it is 10) I want to copy 10 rows of this three column data to another worksheet named ' Target Data' by running a macro. I do not have knowledge to write VBA Code.

When I change the number from 10 to 18 in the single cell Range named 'copy_rows'and run the Macro it must copy 18 rows to worksheet "Target Data"

Comment: Are you asking for help with the VBA code to write the macro? Do you want to learn VBA? Or would a cell formula solution be OK?

Comment: It will be very easy to reference the "source cell" to "target cell". Just put `=A1` or whatever the source address on the target cell.

Comment: cell formula solution is what i am looking for.